# If $A∩B=A′∩B′$ for $A,A'$ and $B,B'$ independent, do we have $A=A′$ and $B=B′$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ two independent sigma-algebra, and $A,A' \in \mathcal{A}$, $B,B' \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $A \cap B=A' \cap B' $, and $P(A)P(B)>0$. Do we have $A=A'$ and $B=B'$?

Comment: Of course not: just choose two pairs of disjoint events...

Comment: i do not understand your reply. can you give details?

Comment: independent events cannot be disjoint...

Answer (score 1):

No. Think of two independent dice. Take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first die's roll and let $\mathcal{B}$ correspond to the second. Devise $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $A\cap B=\{1 \mbox{ is rolled on each die}\}$. They're independent, and there are lots ways to construct such an $A$ and $B$.